# CefSharp DOM in C#

Tags: c#, dom, cefsharp

Until now I was using geckofx. But for several reasons, I try to migrate to a *chromium web engine*.

I have tried CefSharp, and it's seems to be a good alternative. My problem is the use of the DOM (Document Access Model) in C#.

With geckofx, I was making xpath queries that returns some C# GeckoNodes. I do not see the same thing in CefSharp.

I saw that we can query DOM using Javascript, but it will complicate the task for me : using this, I cannot retrieve an entire list of nodes. Only simple values.

- Is there is any other way to get the **DOM in C#** (even using
  debugging protocol)?
- Does other projects than CefSharp propose a Chromium Web engine with 
  DOM access in C#?